# How to increase size of Android ActionBar containing custom view?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

How can I get the stock Android ActionBar to grow so that a moderate-sized custom view contained in the action bar is not truncated?  I am using tabbed navigation on the action bar and the custom view contains a 3x3 GridLayout, but only the top row of the grid layout is showing (in the first row of the action bar, beside the app icon).  Each cell in the grid layout is small (say, a button, icon or text item), but I need more than one row of information to get displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The action bar height won't grow automatically, as you've found out.  It's not wrap_content, it's a set number by default.  You can set the height yourself:

[Change Actionbar height on Android JellyBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098206/change-actionbar-height-on-android-jellybean)