# Adjust ActionBar Heights Separately

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to have the top action bar have a height of 50dp and the bottom tab bar to have a height of 70dp.

Right now, in my style.xml, I have the code

```
<style name="Theme.ActionBarSize" parent="AppBaseTheme">
<item name="android:actionBarSize">60dip</item>
```

But this changes the height of both action bars to 60dp when I put it in Manifest, which isn't something I would want. How can I customize the height of each action bar separately?

Comment: You can check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098206/change-actionbar-height-on-android-jellybean

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom style for `android:actionBarSplitStyle` and `android:actionBarStyle`.

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Your.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarSplitStyle">@style/Your.Split.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Your.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:height">60dp</item>
</style>

<style name="Your.Split.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:height">70dp</item>
</style>
```

[image: Example]