# ActionBar and Tabs not the same height

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I'm trying to modify the size of the action bar and the tabs under it. In ActionBarSherlock that's simple enough:

```
<dimen name="actionBarSize">100dp</dimen>
<style name="Mytheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/actionBarSize</item>
</style>
```

This works in Ice Cream Sandwich and lower. But if I try this in Jelly Bean, the actual ActionBar is resized to 100dp, but the tabs underneath are still the default size. Is there a new setting I'm missing?

EDIT:

OK, I've made a discovery that may be a clue. I changed:

```
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Mytheme" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView">
```

to

```
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Mytheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionBar.TabView">
```

and the whole action bar disappeared. BUT when I changed it back, I still didn't get an action bar back!!!

Comment: What package are you importing ?

Comment: I have not found any solution by which you can customize the size of action bar tab in Jelly Bean.You will find a lot of solution that will work in  Ice Cream Sandwich but not in jelly bean. You can also customize the action bar size but can not customize the action bar tab size. here is similar question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098206/change-actionbar-height-on-android-jellybean