# How to make custom tabs android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

How do i make a tab bar look like this:

[image]

Yes, this is the tab of contact app of android 4.2.2 on samsung galaxy s3.

This is what I have so far:

[image]

As you can see, the **height** of the tabs is a bit low so the indicator override the text. So I need to increase the tab bar **height**.

The problem is I can't increase the height of the tabs further. Because of new android policy that limit tabs height ( it is explained here: [Change Actionbar height on Android JellyBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098206/change-actionbar-height-on-android-jellybean)).

Then how did google do that? Is there any tutorial to make a custom tab bar, or is there a trick to by pass limit of tab bar **height**?

Thank you very much for reading my quesion.

Comment: Those answers don't work, they mention it in the comments.

Comment: it does increase the action bar height i guess. try it once

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#actionBarSize. the docs has no mention of that the height does not change. also the link you posted op wanted to change the height of tabbar

Comment: yup I tried, it did increase to a limit, which is 48 dp for galaxy s3. The tab bar in the picture is already at the limit, 48dp ...

Comment: Yes, he want to increase the height of the tab bar to 80dp, and couldn't do it because of the 48 dp limit ...

Comment: you won't need more than the limit. however the does not say anything about restriction. so i guess it should work

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml?av=f

Comment: Please check: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml
Find attribute: "action_bar_stacked_max_height"

Comment: but why do you require a action bar height to be increased so much and probably using a custom action bar would help

Comment: Well, I just want the indicator not to override the text as in the picture I provide.