# set Actionbar height in SlidingTabsColors

Tags: android

i`m using [SlidingTabsColors](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsColors)

how can i set actionbar height?!i mean is grey zone in [this image](http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/18477143119150942830_Screenshot_%DB%B2%DB%B0%DB%B1%DB%B5-%DB%B0%DB%B5-%DB%B0%DB%B9-%DB%B2%DB%B1-%DB%B2%DB%B1-%DB%B2%DB%B9.png)

Is this Actionbar?!! on this project MainActivity is extends from SampleActivityBase and SampleActivityBase is extends from FragmentActivity, so those are not extends from ActionBarActivity.

Update :

i changed activity_main to this codes :

```
<LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/sample_main_layout">

    <View
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
          android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/sample_content_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="0px" />

</LinearLayout>
```

you can see changed in here :

http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/1851014311926138348_dffdff.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are talking about the grey area containing the SlidingTabsColors text?

This area is not the ActionBar this is the title which was used in very old Android apps.

I highly recommend you to use the newest `support libraries` and the newest `appcompat library`, and then use a `Theme.AppCompat` style in your application.

This will display a real `ActionBar` with the correct height, and hide the `TitleBar` you see in your app.

---

To use the newest appcompat library add the following to your **build.gradle**

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1"
```

After this add the following as style to your activity (or application)

```
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity"
        android:theme="Theme.AppCompat"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ....
</application>
```

Comment: thanks, how can i change tabs color? i mean is background not divider

Comment: as of the background i would assume the `android:background` attribute via xml or the `setBackground` via code. Not sure where you define the other colors.

Answer (score 0):

To get height of the ActionBar in XML, just use

```
?android:attr/actionBarSize
```

you can use it to set height  like this

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
 />
```

Comment: Which xml file? activity_main?

Comment: where you want to set acttionbar height to view

Comment: i udate my question can you check again?

Comment: what you want can you come again ?

Comment: check SlidingTabsColors files in android example, i don`t know Which file  i have to edite to set actionbar height

Comment: activity main is view for that

Comment: well check my code in my question, i add your code to my view, but it is not change actionbar height : http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/1851014311926138348_dffdff.png

Comment: please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098206/change-actionbar-height-on-android-jellybean

Answer (score 0):

```
<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
 />
```

Comment: i change activity_main with your code but:http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/1851014311926138348_dffdff.png

Comment: You need to apply this to your View, mine is just a sample, don't add it to your xml.

Comment: problem is i don`t know Which file is view for that